# Using gulp-inline-source and ES6 code in scripts

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, gulp, browserify, es6-modules

Is there a way to use gulp-inline-source with ES6 / ES2015 ?

So basically I need to import other node style JS files in inlineScript.js as in in the example in https://github.com/fmal/gulp-inline-source/blob/master/README.md

Trying browserify with gulp but running into issues in the inlinesource task for scripts that import other modules.

Context: I need my build folder JS as inline within HTML. But some of those JS import other JS modules.

Here's what I have in `inlineScript.js`

```
import bar from './bar';

function component() {
var element = document.createElement('div');
element.innerHTML = 'Hello Gulp!!';
return element;
}

document.body.appendChild(component());

bar();
```

and in `bar.js`

```
export default function bar() {
console.log('gulp bar js');
}
```

I only want to use `inlineScript.js` in the HTML with `inline` attribute but need the code in `bar.js` imported the final inline script.

Comment: Can you provide an example of your inlineScript.js file please, this will help the community better answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

I know its an old post..

Did you try https://github.com/exuanbo/gulp-inline-source-html ?

In the readme it states `This plugin is based on fmal/gulp-inline-source, which is no longer maintained. It now supports Gulp.js v4 and ES6 / ES2015.`

Works for me, cheers